# How to access methods and properties in java-script class from DART

Tags: angular-dart, dart-js-interop, webusb, dart

Not sure if its a compiler limitation or something I don't understand (likely the last :-))

I'm trying to access a "DataView" structure buried in an native java-script class.
I got it to work in debug mode; however, when compiled for deployment, the solution isn't working.

```
  await _transferIn(adapter, 5, 64).then((usbInTransferResult){
    log.finest('_transferIn.then');
    js.context['console'].callMethod('log', [usbInTransferResult]);

    var rxLen = usbInTransferResult['data']['byteLength'];  <<<<< Fails
    for( var index = 0; index < rxLen; index++ ){
      rxData.add(usbInTransferResult['data'].callMethod('getUint8', [index]));  <<<<< Fails
    };

    log.finest(rxData);
    return completer.complete(rxData);
  });
```

The above code reads a data packet received through USB (WebUSB). It reads the received package length and puts it copies each byte into a `List<int>`. In both places (reading the property `byteLength` and calling method `getUint8([index])` fails only when compiled for deployment.

Below a picture of the reported error
[image: Snapshot Error]

Below a picture of a successful run (in debug mode)
Please notice the additional DART symbols (which are missing in the picture above).
[image: Snapshot success]

ps.
I'm using DART-SDK 2.0.0 (tried also 2.1.0-dev.8.0), and Angular-DART 5.0.0, within a WebStorm project.

Comment: I think you meant to say "javascript" instead of "java" above.

Answer (score 0):

See the [`js` package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) and it's documentation for how to wrap a javascript API with something callable from Dart.

Comment: Hi Nate.Thanks for the feedback. As I'm struggling a bit maybe you can point a bit further. The challenge I'm facing is with a structure passed to DART through a callback (It seems js package addresses the other-way around from DART -> JS). Please also remember, the solution works in debug mode, but fails when deployed.